# Deleting log files automatically every X days in Linux

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, logging, delete-file

I'm new here and I need some helps.
I have some application who are made of and use few things like alfresco, share, postgresql, camunda...

Each use of the application is followed by the saving of logs in folders like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbbi9.png

I need to set the system to automatically delete logs from these folders every X days.
Does somebody know how can I do that in Ubuntu 20.04?

And I apologize if I didn't define the question well, but like I said, I'm new to this area.

Thanks in advance :)

I tried to add a few lines of code in the docker-compose.yml file, but I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions specifically.  This question may be a better fit on https://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a [Logrotate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-20-04).

It will need to update (re-build) your docker image. It can't simply do it in docker-compose.yml. But I have no idea how is it. Therefore, you have to modify my guide below by yourself to fit into your case.

Install logrotate

```
apt install -y logrotate
```

Let's say you have

- `/home/demo/alfreco/logs/postgres/errors.log`
- `/home/demo/alfreco/logs/postgres/slow.log`

Then, you can

```
vi /etc/logrotate.d/custom-postgres
```

Don't forget to change placeholder  to your desired number

```
/home/demo/alfreco/logs/postgres/*.log {
  rotate <X days>
  daily
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

anacron will also be needed to trigger the rotation periodically

```
apt install -y anacron
```

Then start it in the background.

How does your entrypoint look like? If you use supervisor, add the following to your config (`/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`).

```
[program:anacron]
command=/usr/sbin/anacron -d
process_name=%(program_name)s
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```